# pySpark using mapInPandas instead of rdd.mapPartitions - is it equivalent

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have code that need to run on each "id" where multiple of those can appear in a stream batch, and where the stream is partitioned by the id
where the stream contains multiple instances with the same id, that need to be merged - according to the sorted order

So currently, in order to run the "merge" function on all items with the same id, I run it as rdd.mapPartitions

```
mergedRdd = partitionedDf.rdd.mapPartitions(merge_payloads) # We use partition

mergedDf = spark.createDataFrame(mergedRdd)
```

From what I understand currently, I pay a performance steep price because of transformations from jvm to python and vice versa and was suggested to move to `applyInPandas` pyspark functions instead.

so what I figured I could be doing is something like

```
mergeDf = partitionedDf.groupBy('id').applyInPandas(merge_payloads_pd, 'id long, payload string')
```

Is this really equivalent but with the added bonus of Arrow based python/jvm transformations? or am I missing something here

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by equivalent e.g. Are you asking whether it is functionally equivalent from the user perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#grouped-map), using applyInPandas function, spark uses Arrow and accelerates processing time, avoiding serialization/deserialization time. You need to hace pyarrow installed and the configuration spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled set to true.

Comment: Thanks although this doesn't answer the actual question. which is : are the those two different transformations mapPartitions and the groupBy.applyInPandas - equivalent